# Action method to delete a user with ASP.NET Identity 3.x

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-identity-3

**Here is my action method to delete a user:**
I feel like it is blocking since I am using `user.Result` to pass the actual user object from one async result to the next async method. Is there a better way to do this?

```
// POST: Users/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    var user = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id.ToString());
    var result = await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user.Result);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. Using the `user.Result` to pass the actual object is blocking the async method.

Best practice in using `async` is to use `await` all the way through the method. **Don’t mix blocking and async code**.

```
// POST: Users/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id) {
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id.ToString());
    var result = await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Source - [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)